# Google Adwords + Analytics without a website

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I haven't finished my website yet, but I want to play with Google Adwords. But *how to link Google Adwords to Google Analytics if you haven't a website?*

Google provides you with [GA demo account](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6367342?hl=en#access), but if to follow [link manual](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1704341?hl=en) with demo GA account you won't see any options on the 5th step:

[image: Google Adwords GA integration page]

Comment: You can create an GA account and link it without having a website (to limited use, an account without data is pretty pointless). The demo account displays data from the Google Merchandise store, so Google won't let you make changes to that.

Comment: @EikePierstorff then how to link them? Adwords doesn't propose any options in Google Analytics tab